# Having problem assigning a device variable in CUDA

Tags: cuda

I'm having trouble trying to assign a value to a device variable and then copying this to a host variable.

I start with d_test and h_test = 0.0. I have a simple kernel to set the device variable, d_test, to 1.0. I then copy this to the host variable h_test and print. The problem is that when I print I get h_test = 0.0. What am I doing wrong? Here's the code:

```
// -*- mode: C -*-
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

// device variable and kernel
__device__ float d_test;
__global__ void kernel1(float d_test) { d_test = 1.0; }


int main() {

  // initialise variables
  float h_test = 0.0;
  cudaMemset(&d_test,0,sizeof(float));

  // invoke kernel
  kernel1 <<<1,1>>> (d_test);

  // Copy device variable to host and print
  cudaMemcpy(&h_test,&d_test,sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  printf("%f\n",h_test);  

}
```

Comment: using quote inside cudaMemcpyFromSymbol causes 0.0 after copy operation so just remove quote signs to make it works.

Comment: What version of CUDA are you using?

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of issues with your code.

1. As pezcode correctly notes, `kernel1`'s parameter `d_test` shadows your global variable, so when it assigns to `d_test`, it is actually changing the value of its parameter, instead of the global variable as you intend.  `kernel1` need not take an argument in this example.
2. Instead of `cudaMemcpy`, use `cudaMemcpyFromSymbol` when copying from a global `__device__` variable.

Here's the full solution:

```
// -*- mode: C -*-
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

// device variable and kernel
__device__ float d_test;
__global__ void kernel1() { d_test = 1.0; }

int main() {

  // initialise variables
  float h_test = 0.0;
  cudaMemset(&d_test,0,sizeof(float));

  // invoke kernel
  kernel1 <<<1,1>>> ();

  // Copy device variable to host and print
  cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&h_test, d_test, sizeof(float), 0, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  // or cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&h_test, "d_test", sizeof(float), 0, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  // until CUDA 5.0
  printf("%f\n",h_test);  
}
```

And the output:

```
$ nvcc test.cu -run
1.000000
```

UPDATE 2019 nov

[CUDA Toolkit documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__HIGHLEVEL.html#group__CUDART__HIGHLEVEL_1g99db510d18d37fbb0f5c075a8caf3b5f) states that "use of a string naming a variable as the symbol parameter was deprecated in CUDA 4.1 and removed in CUDA 5.0."

Comment: at this moment, `cudaMemset` returns error msg: 'cudaMemset'; and `cudaMemcpyFromSymbol` returns error msg: 'returns error msg' (API has changed, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9997978/1150712)

Comment: not sure exactly why, but it works once you remove the quotes (e.g. cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&h_test, "d_test", sizeof(float), 0, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost); )

Answer (score 4):

cudaMemcpyFromSymbol worked for me after struggling quite a while with cudaMemcpy and getting the wrong values back. I had to remove the quotes around "d_test" and got an invalid argument error with the cudaMemset, so just used the cudaMalloc which was previously in the code.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that kernel1 changes its parameter d_test as it hides the global **device** variable.
Rename one of them or if that works with CUDA, explicitly use global scope by setting ::d_test.

Comment: I've changed the name of d_test to test in the kernel, but that hasn't made any difference. What's the global scope ::d_test thingy?

Comment: For some reason I thought you were using C++ where you can use scope::var to access a variable in a specific scope. Just using :: would mean global scope, thus accessing the global variable hidden away by the function parameter with the same name. Sorry for the confusion :s

Answer (score 0):

this code work for me fine  . the key is there  .

the second variable should be like this   \n

cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&h_test, d_test, sizeof(float), 0,  cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

and then compile your code with
 nvcc -Xcompiler -arch=sm_30 sample.cu  -o sample.exe