# cudaMemset fails on __device__ variable

Tags: cuda

I am having trouble using `cudaMemset` on a device variable. Is it possible to use the reference to the device variable for `cudaMemset`, or is it just a matter of missing compiler flags, or libraries.. I am using cuda 4.1, and

> NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  285.05.33  Thu Jan 19
>   14:07:02 PST 2012

This is my sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

// device variable and kernel
__device__ float d_test;

int main() {

  if (cudaMemset(&d_test,0,sizeof(float)) !=cudaSuccess)
        printf("Error!\n");
}
```

which outputs:

```
Error!
```

Comment: cudaGetSymbolAddress doesn't work for me.
Do I need to add some compiler flag?
I copy the code above but it says GPUassert: invalid device symbol XXXX.cu 24

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that `d_test` (as it appears in the host symbol table) isn't a valid device address and the runtime cannot access it directly. The solution is to use the `cudaGetSymbolAddress` API function to read the address of the device symbol from the context at runtime. Here is a slightly expanded version of your demonstration case which should work correctly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

// device variable and kernel
__device__ float d_test;

inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char * file, int line, bool Abort=true)
{
    if (code != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code),file,line);
        if (Abort) exit(code);
    }       
}

#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }

int main()
{

    float * _d_test;

    gpuErrchk( cudaFree(0) );
    gpuErrchk( cudaGetSymbolAddress((void **)&_d_test, "d_test") );
    gpuErrchk( cudaMemset(_d_test,0,sizeof(float)) );

    gpuErrchk( cudaThreadExit() );

    return 0;
}
```

Here, we read the address of the device symbol `d_test` from the context into a host pointer `_d_test`. This can then be passed to host side API functions like `cudaMemset`, `cudaMemcpy`, etc.

---

Edit to note that the form of `cudaGetSymbolAddress` shown in this answer has been deprecated and removed from the CUDA runtime API. For modern CUDA, the call would be:

```
gpuErrchk( cudaGetSymbolAddress((void **)&_d_test, d_test) );
```

Comment: Thanks! this works.. good to know about the 'cudaGetSymbolAddress' function to extract symbol address from the context.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can also use cudaMemcpyFromSymbol:
A function, such as the following kernel, can change the value of the variable declared in global memory (outside of the main function)

```
__global__ void kernel1() { d_test = 1.0; }
```

Inside your main, you can obtain the value using cudaMemcpyFromSymbol

```
cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&h_test,"d_test",sizeof(float),0,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

Of course, there is also cudaMemcpyToSymbol to change the value of the global variable.

The idea came from here: [Having problem assigning a device variable in CUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871854/having-problem-assigning-a-device-variable-in-cuda)

Comment: Note that the form of `cudaMemcpyFromSymbol` call shown in this answer is long deprecated and isn't supported in either CUDA 5 or CUDA 6