# Exception 'cudaError_enum' thrown in cudaGetExportTable (CUDA runtime library)?

Tags: exception, cuda, mpi, icc

I am debugging a MPI-based CUDA program with DDT.  My code aborts when the CUDA runtime library (libcudart) throws an exception in the (undocumented) function `cudaGetExportTable`, when called from `cudaMalloc` and `cudaThreadSynchronize` (UPDATED: using `cudaDeviceSynchronize` gives the same error) in my code.

Why is libcudart throwing an exception (I am using the C API, not the C++ API) before I can detect it in my code with its `cudaError_t` return value or with `CHECKCUDAERROR`?

(I'm using CUDA 4.2 SDK for Linux.)

Output:

```
Process 9: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cudaError_enum'
Process 9: terminate called recursively

Process 20: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cudaError'
Process 20: terminate called recursively
```

My code:

```
cudaThreadSynchronize();
CHECKCUDAERROR("cudaThreadSynchronize()");
```

Other code fragment:

```
const size_t t;  // from argument to function
void* p=NULL;
const cudaError_t r=cudaMalloc(&p, t);
if (r!=cudaSuccess) {
    ERROR("cudaMalloc failed.");
}
```

Partial Backtrace:

```
Process 9:
cudaDeviceSynchronize()
-> cudaGetExportTable()
   -> __cxa_throw

Process 20:
cudaMalloc()
-> cudaGetExportTable()
   -> cudaGetExportTable()
      -> __cxa_throw
```

Memory debugging errors:

```
Processes 0,2,4,6-9,15-17,20-21:
Memory error detected in Malloc_cuda_gx (cudamalloc.cu:35):
dmalloc bad admin structure list.
```

This line is the cudaMalloc code fragment shown above. Also:

```
Processes 1,3,5,10-11,13-14,18-19,23:
Memory error detected in vfprintf from /lib64/libc.so.6:
dmalloc bad admin structure list.
```

Also, when running on 3 cores/gpus per node instead of 4 gpus per node, dmalloc detects similar memory errors, but when not in debug mode, the code runs perfectly fine with 3 gpus per node (as far as I can tell).

Comment: How many MPI processes are you running when this happens?

Comment: I'm running with 24 processes across 6 nodes (4 cores and gpus per node).

Comment: `cudaThreadSynchronize` is technically deprecated. What happens if you try `cudaDeviceSychronize` instead?

Comment: Using `cudaDeviceSynchronize` gives the exact same error.

Comment: Ok. `cudaGetExportTable` is an internal context symbol management routine which should never fail the way you are seeing. So either you have found a bug (perhaps try the cuda 5 beta and newer version of the runtime and driver), or you code has corrupted something with a buffer overrun.

Comment: That's good to know.  Since I'm running this on a shared cluster, I'd prefer to eliminate the latter possibility first.  Would running with `cuda-memcheck` reliably detect a buffer overrun in this case?

Comment: @talonmies: I do not believe there are *any* behavior differences between cudaThreadSynchronize() and cudaDeviceSynchronize().  They just changed the name to be more descriptive.

Comment: @BenWibking: I suspect a driver mismatch. Are you sure all the machines in the cluster are running a driver suitable for the CUDA runtime used by your application?

Comment: I think the driver is correct.  `nvcc` reports: `Cuda compilation tools, release 4.2, V0.2.1221` and `modinfo nvidia` reports `version:        295.41` on all of the nodes.

Comment: Memory debugging reveals: `Processes 0,2,4,6-9,15-17,20-21: Memory error detected in Malloc_cuda_gx (cudamalloc.cu:35): dmalloc bad admin structure list`.  This line is the `cudaMalloc` code fragment shown above.  Also: `Processes 1,3,5,10-11,13-14,18-19,23: Memory error detected in vfprintf from /lib64/libc.so.6: dmalloc bad admin structure list`.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Recompile with gcc.  (I was using icc to compile my code.)

When you do this, the exception appears when debugging, but continuing past it, I get real CUDA errors:

```
Process 9: gadget_cuda_gx.cu:116: ERROR in gadget_cuda_gx.cu:919: CUDA ERROR:   cudaThreadSynchronize(): unspecified launch failure
Process 20: cudamalloc.cu:38: ERROR all CUDA-capable devices are busy or unavailable, cudaMalloc failed to allocate 856792 bytes = 0.817101 Mb
```

Valgrind reveals no memory corruption or leaks in my code (either compiling with gcc or icc), but does find a few leaks in libcudart.

UPDATE: Still not fixed.  Appears to be the same problem reported in answer #2 to this thread: [cudaMemset fails on __device__ variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996563/cudamemset-fails-on-device-variable).  The runtime isn't working like it should, it seems...

Comment: That was a pretty huge omission - icc isn't supported! The unspecified launch failure probably means out of bounds memory access in your kernel somewhere. You can use cuda-memcheck standalone or inside cuda-gdb to get more diagnostics.

Comment: Ah, good to know.  I discovered that the code that has been passed down to me uses variable scoping semantics incorrectly.  However, I cannot find an idiomatic way to reproduce the correct behavior.  The relevant device function declares and returns a `dim3 result;` which obviously goes out of scope upon return.  However, the `result` variable should be thread-local (it stores the thread, block info) and modifiable, which does not appear to be possible in CUDA...?

Comment: Ok, so it turns out neither of these was the problem. (I upgraded to CUDA 5 and now the error reporting is working better.) I can reproduce the error I'm getting with `cudaGetSymbolAddress` from some code that you posted on another thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996563/cudamemset-fails-on-device-variable.  So it seems that something is broken...